# I need to remove the header rows(?) from my filtered and copied data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, header, spreadsheet

EDITED: To include image of data after code runs.

I have a google sheet that is holding some data that is specific to a percentage. When this percentage is reached then that row is no longer needed. I would like to copy it to another sheet to keep it in archive. I have a tick box that will be used to select multiple rows that are no longer needed and I will have a button that will run the script to move the rows.
I have tried a few iterations of code but each time an extra row at the top is copied. I have tried various functions such as offset, rowDepth, shift but no luck. (I possibly haven't put the code in the correct place.)

This is a screenshot of the data layout:
[Layout of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6hXo.png)

And this is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
function create_filter(){
    
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
   const range = sheet1.getRange("A:S");
   const  filter = range.createFilter();
   const  filterCriteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo('TRUE')
   const col1 = 19;

   const add_filter1 =filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col1,filterCriteria1); 

   Logger.log("Filter has been added.");

   var rangeData = sheet1.getDataRange();
    
   const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
   
   range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange(3,1));

   filter.remove();
}
```

What I end up copying:
[You can see the extra row here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT5LU.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshots suggest that rows `Archive!1:2` already contain the headers as static text. You are copying all of `range` below those two rows. The problem is that `range` includes the header row. You can try fixing that like this:

```
   const range = sheet1.getRange('A2:S');
```

You are overwriting the previous data in `Archive` each time you run the script. To append data rather than overwrite it, you can use the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function, like this:

```
function archiveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getRange('Template!A3:S')
    .getValues()
    .filter(row => row[18]); // column S
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  appendRows_(targetSheet, values, 1);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that worked for me. How does the filter know what to filter by?

Comment: Also, is it difficult to remove the copied rows from the 'Template' sheet?
I've tried
`const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Template");

const colSData = ws.getRange('S3:S').getValues();

for(let i =colSData.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  if(colSData[i][0] == true){
    //console.log(colSData);
    ws.deleteRows(i+1);
  }
}`

Comment: The [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call will keep rows where column 18 (zero-indexed column S) contains a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. In other words, it leaves out rows where checkboxes remain unticked. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).